# Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.themoviedb.org

Tags: java, android

Edit: The emulator didn't have internet :/ if you're having this problem try going to the AVD manager and wiping the emulator.

My code was working before I added the adapter but I've triple checked it and my asynhttprequest still isn't working (before it was returning a status code of 200 and the results and movies variables).  Any ideas are appreciated, I've tried both the emulator and a phone so I know internet isn't the issue.

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flixster">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`MainActivity.java:`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String NOW_PLAYING_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=a07e22bc18f5cb106bfe4cc1f83ad8ed";
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

List<Movie> movies;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView rvMovies = findViewById(R.id.rvMovies);
    movies = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create the adapter
    final MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movies);

    // Set the adapter on the recycler view
    rvMovies.setAdapter(movieAdapter);

    // Set a Layout Manager on the recycler view
    rvMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(NOW_PLAYING_URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Headers headers, JSON json) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
            JSONObject jsonObject = json.jsonObject;
            try {
                JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                Log.i(TAG, "Results: " + results.toString());
                movies.addAll(Movie.fromJsonArray(results));
                // whenever data changes, rerender recycler view
                //movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i(TAG, "Movies: " + movies.size());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Hit json exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Headers headers, String response, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");
        }
    });
}}
```

`Movie.java`

```
public class Movie {


String posterPath;
String title;
String overview;



public Movie (JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    posterPath = jsonObject.getString("poster_path");
    title = jsonObject.getString("title");
    overview = jsonObject.getString("overview");
}

// Iterates through data from results array returned by MainActivity.java into individual movie objects
public static List<Movie> fromJsonArray(JSONArray movieJsonArray) throws JSONException {
    List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < movieJsonArray.length(); i++){
        movies.add(new Movie(movieJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
    }
    return movies;
}

// TODO: figure out what sizes are available and then append to url before posterPath
public String getPosterPath() {
    return String.format("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/%s", posterPath);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}
}
```

`MovieAdapter.java`

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<Movie>  movies;

public MovieAdapter (Context context, List<Movie>movies) {
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
}

// Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View movieView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(movieView);
}

// Involves populating data into the item through holder
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get the movie at the passed in position
    Movie movie = movies.get(position);
    // Bind the movie data into the viewholder
    holder.bind(movie);
}

// Returns the total count of items in the list
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvOverview;
    ImageView ivPoster;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvOverview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvOverview);
        ivPoster= itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPoster);
    }

        public void bind(Movie movie) {
            tvTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
            tvOverview.setText(movie.getOverview());
            Glide.with(context).load(movie.getPosterPath()).into(ivPoster);

        }
    }
}
```

`StackTrace`

```
2020-02-11 22:47:53.186 28424-28424/? I/xample.flixste: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-02-11 22:47:53.444 28424-28424/? E/xample.flixste: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000


2020-02-11 22:47:53.539 28424-28424/? W/xample.flixste: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86


2020-02-11 22:47:55.018 28424-28462/com.example.flixster D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.


2020-02-11 22:47:55.012 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:168): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=274 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0


2020-02-11 22:47:55.022 28424-28462/com.example.flixster W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)


2020-02-11 22:47:55.082 28424-28462/com.example.flixster D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so


2020-02-11 22:47:55.114 28424-28462/com.example.flixster D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so


2020-02-11 22:47:55.133 28424-28462/com.example.flixster D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so


2020-02-11 22:47:55.769 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:55.770 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)

2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.241 28424-28424/com.example.flixster W/xample.flixste: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
2020-02-11 22:47:56.242 28424-28424/com.example.flixster D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default


2020-02-11 22:47:56.473 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe1632190, tid 28459


2020-02-11 22:47:56.491 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 


2020-02-11 22:47:56.597 28424-28459/com.example.flixster W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-02-11 22:47:56.604 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0


2020-02-11 22:47:56.604 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe161a120: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3


2020-02-11 22:47:56.609 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe161a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe160f700)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.629 28424-28459/com.example.flixster W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported


2020-02-11 22:47:56.633 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/HostConnection: createUnique: call


2020-02-11 22:47:56.638 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe16322d0, tid 28459


2020-02-11 22:47:56.640 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 


2020-02-11 22:47:56.641 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2020-02-11 22:47:56.641 28424-28459/com.

example.flixster D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff801000 size 0x2000


2020-02-11 22:47:56.666 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe161a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe160f700)


2020-02-11 22:47:56.669 28424-28459/com.example.flixster D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0


2020-02-11 22:47:56.872 28424-28464/com.example.flixster D/MainActivity: onFailure
```

Comment: Full stack-trace would help more.

Comment: @CHN I added them

Comment: Include the throwable variable t in this statement -> 'Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");' and get the information and update your question

Comment: @mmmmz which OS you are testing? Check for https url is whitelisted or not. See https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: @mmmmz your stack trace doesn't have the error you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways

**1.** add below attribute into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

**Reason**

Applications intending to connect to destinations using only secure connections can opt-out of supporting cleartext (using the unencrypted HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS) to those destinations. This option helps prevent accidental regressions in apps due to changes in URLs provided by external sources such as backend servers

**2.** add DNS to your okhttp client.

```
return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .dns(Dns.SYSTEM)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```